# libxmlrpc iterate through struct

Tags: c++, loops, struct

I am implementing libxmlrpc into  C++ project, anywayy, my RPC server has returned a struct with 52 member structs in them.

I do not know what the keys are as they are opaque references, so I cannot rely on them.

How can I iterate through the struct, I would have thought it was with the following code:

```
XmlRpcValue param_array = XmlRpcValue::makeArray();
param_array.arrayAppendItem(XmlRpcValue::makeString(this->sessionKey));
param_array.arrayAppendItem(XmlRpcValue::makeString("petabytes"));

XmlRpcValue result = ServerCall("Charter.getDataWarehouse.storage.capacity", param_array, url);
int index = 0;
while(index < result.structSize())
{
    XmlRpcValue Data = result.getStruct();


    //Would have thought it would work with this ;( shit documentation libxmlrpc has, grrrr
    //Data.structGetKeyAndValue(index);

    //This for example works, because I know the opaque reference, but in real life I wont
    cout << Data.structGetValue("OpaqueRef:d4e60db6-2271-b0ac-d362-1b51220980af").structSize() << endl;
    index++;
}
```

However, Data.structGetKeyAndValue(index) errors with:

```
no matching function for call to 'XmlRpcValue::structGetKeyAndValue(int&)
```

Which is fine, I understand it's not a public (well I think it's not a public member function) of `xmlrpcvalue`, however I cannot find anything that would allow me to do this.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Some quick Googling seems to indicate that you've got the function signature wrong:

```
void XmlRpcValue::structGetKeyAndValue(const int index, std::string& out_key, XmlRpcValue& out_value);
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. it didn't solve the issue, It turned out that direct libxmlrpc was a bit daunting for my task, I ended up going with fastrpc (I needed to finish the project fast unfortunately..) and well... fastrpc is.. fast!